# unexpected allocation request that exceeds 2GB error

Tags: linux, memory, swap, memory-limit

I have a system with 32GB ram and 200GB of swap partition with Debian Linux (Jessie) and working with ABAQUS software to simulate complex phenomena. I've tested many test cases and they run without any error but now I want to run a test case which should need about 100GB of ram (or more or less). The problem id that it fills the RAM totally and even about 10GB of swap space but then it returns an error "**unexpected allocation request that exceeds 2GB**". the system is obviously **64bit** and the software package is also 64bit. I checked that the same error will occur when about 50GB of RAM was filled.

I don't know what is limiting the process and why the error message tells **2GB** as it already have about 40GB allocated?

Comment: Have you been in contact with their support people?

Comment: You need more RAM instead of allocating such a huge amount of swap. By the time you get to a few tens of GBs the system is already crawling to death and probably you'll never reach 100GB of swap. Better use zram instead of disk swap

Comment: @phuclv: the software needs this amount of RAM only for some preprocessing and then the main process is done in parallel through some compute nodes in a cluster. as I mentioned, I checked the 64GB system and the error is still here!

Comment: if there's no contiguous address range available then the allocation will be failed, although it's unlikely on a 64-bit system. See if these helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/14612538/995714 http://abaqus-users.1086179.n5.nabble.com/memory-problem-td23709.html